# Is there a possibility to pray to north or south in some countries in the world?

Tags: tefilla

Is there a possibility to pray towards north or south in some countries in the world? or it is always towards eastern or western directions (depending on the country obviously)?

Answer (score 3):

It's commonly accepted (and often practiced) that we face Israel during the *amida* prayer. Details are in *Orach Chayim* 94. So someone in Dniepropetrovsk (due north of Israel) would indeed face south.

As always, consult with your rabbi rather than relying for practical matters on what you read on this site.

Comment: Apparently the city's name was changed to [Dnipro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dnipro) (like the river's name in Ukrainian) in 2016

Comment: Additionally, within Israel, one prays facing Jeruasalem, so in the north of Israel one would pray facing south (Jerusalem is right about the center), and vice versa.